# Full Control Permission Problem

Tags: permissions, security

I am in a group which has Full Permission (site collection owners).

However i cant add users to groups that i am not a member off.

I thought this would give me full overriding permissions.

Am i misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to be part of the "site collection administrators". Groups are housed in the same area, and allow the owner or site collection administrator to change them.

Site Collection Root -> Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Administrators

Answer (score 1):

In group settings there is a page "Group Settings" which can be accessed thorough:
(Group Page) > Settings > Group Settings

3rd section is group settings section where you can set "Who can edit the membership of the group?" which in default is "Group Owner". In the same page you can change group owner which in default is 1st site collection administrator.

In your case I believe that in all groups, **"Who can edit the membership of the group?"** is set to **"Group Members"** *and* you are **not** the group owner in any of the groups. Therefore, you are just able to edit membership in those groups you are a member of. Other group memberships can only be edited by site collection administrator.